# WPF project Taskmanger icon

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I have a WPF project. when I run it, the icon appers in the Taskbar and in the app. But in the Taskmanger windows app it's blank, how can I change that?

I have the "icon" property set on the window. And also the projects properties has the icon as its icon.
And also the icon on "programs and features" looks strange

Comment: How many resolution does your ico file has?

Comment: inside ico file there is not only one image. you should have images with different dimensions inside your ico. take a look at answer I have write below

Comment: But how do I make them all in one folder with the same name?

Comment: You do not need to have many images inside folder, you need to have many images inside ico file (like inside zip archive).

Comment: I still don't get a thing of what you're talking about. I have an icon, I converted it into all sizes of ico, how am I supposed to use them all? I imported them but I can only use one of them as an icon

Comment: I have update answer to show you how inside one *.ico file could be stored many images with different resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your ico file has not enough resolutions. Edit it with some graphic software like [Free Icon Editor](http://www.free-icon-editor.com/)

Take a look at [Icons Guidlines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485.aspx)

For Classic Mode, the full set is 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 64x64. (but better have some more resolutions up to 256x256)

Here is screenshot of IcoFX editor with opened icon that has multiple resolutions inside

[image]